# mike42/escpos-php - image dimension

Tags: php, escpos

I have a large PNG file that I would like to print it over the ESCPOS-PHP library. I knew there is something like `MODE_DOUBLE_WIDTH`, but my image is already in a large size so I want to make it smaller.

However I have been looking for the parameter of setting the dimension of a image file, is there any parameter to resize (set the size like 20x20) the image programmatically.

Comment: Please note that your second question (asking for a tool recommendation) is defined as off-topic for this site in the [help]. I would recommend [edit]ing your question to concentrate on the first part, making sure to clarify what you've tried, and what problem you're encountering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mike42/escpos-php will not have a function to convert the size of image data.
The documentation doesn't mention it, and the source code doesn't have that functionality.

If you want to convert some image data file into data of specific vertical and horizontal dot size, please use another library other than mike42/escpos-php or the function of language.

---

**documentation:**
[graphics(EscposImage $image, $size)](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php#graphicsescposimage-image-size)

> Print an image to the printer.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - `EscposImage $img`: The image to print.
> - `int $size`: Output size modifier for the image.
>
> Size modifiers are:
>
> - `IMG_DEFAULT` (leave image at original size)
> - `IMG_DOUBLE_WIDTH`
> - `IMG_DOUBLE_HEIGHT`
>
> The function [bitImage()](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php#bitimageescposimage-image-size) takes the same parameters, and can be used if your printer doesn't support the newer graphics commands. As an additional fallback, the `bitImageColumnFormat()` function is also provided.

**source code:**
[escpos-php/src/Mike42/Escpos/EscposImage.php](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php/blob/development/src/Mike42/Escpos/EscposImage.php)
[escpos-php/src/Mike42/Escpos/GdEscposImage.php](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php/blob/development/src/Mike42/Escpos/GdEscposImage.php)
[escpos-php/src/Mike42/Escpos/ImagickEscposImage.php](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php/blob/development/src/Mike42/Escpos/ImagickEscposImage.php)

---

The specification of `IMG_DEFAULT`, `IMG_DOUBLE_WIDTH`, `IMG_DOUBLE_HEIGHT` is the value specified in the parameter of the ESC/POS command, not the function of converting the image data.

[ESC *](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=88)
[GS /](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=92)
[GS Q 0](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=93)
[GS v 0](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=94)